# Why use event as a parameter in this JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript

What is the point of using `event` as a parameter in this JavaScript function?

```
<script type="text/javascript"› 
    function changeImage(event)
    {
        event = event || window.event;

        var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;

        if (targetElement.tagNamd == "IMG")
        {
            document.getElementbyId("mainImage").src = targetElement.getAttribute("src");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Include code **as code**, not as a picture of code. That way it's searchable, copy-and-pastable, scales well depending on presentation device, ...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) It's not at all clear what you're asking here. "Why use event as a parameter to a function?" So you can use it. For instance, in the above, to know which element fired the event.

Comment: @Ali Abo Saada So targetElement can use the event's target. What's the point of your question???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `event` parameter in this function will give information about the event that triggered it when it is called by an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) somewhere else in the code.

If nothing is passed as `event` (so, it wasn't called from a handler), it defaults to the global `event` variable of the window.

Included in the information from the event is an attribute called either `target` or `srcElement`, depending on the browser being used (hence the check on line 6), which holds the element that was the target of the event.

This element is then modified in various ways using DOM manipulation functions on the last few lines of the block.